# Creating Image Maps for CSS Background Images

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I have a background image set on my html page with the following CSS code:

```html
html { 
  background:  url("assets/Untitled-2.gif") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I would like to add an image map to this gif in order to make certain regions of the gif clickable. I know this can be done in HTML using the `<map>` tag, and I have such a tag prepared for the gif. Is there a way that I can apply this map to the background image using either HTML or CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image map in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705235/image-map-in-css)

Comment: @EternalHour No, my question is different. I can't add the map at the moment because my image is included within the file via CSS, not with the  `<img>` html tag as is customary. Therefore, I don't know how to associate the `<map>` tag with the background image.

Comment: No. You can't add image maps to background images. Only inline images.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's what I was afraid of. Thanks though!

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998331/mapping-background-image-of-element

Comment: You could do something like this though - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha